# Issue in parsing JSON using GSON library

Tags: android, json, gson

I am working on parsing a local `JSON` using `GSON` Library.Here is my json structure

```
{
  "employees":[
  {
   "id":100,
   "name":"Ranjith"
  },
  {
   "id":101,
   "name":"Satheesh"
  }]
}
```

I have to display this in a list view.Here is my code

```
public void loadfromfile()
{
    try {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("sample.json");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        JsonReader reader=new JsonReader(br);
        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {

            String name = reader.nextName();

            if (name.equals("success")) {
                success =reader.nextBoolean();
            }

            else if(name.equals("employees")){
                reader.beginArray();
                while (reader.hasNext()) {

                    Employee employee= gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(reader), Employee.class);

                    emplist.add(employee);
                }
                reader.endArray();
            }
        }

     reader.endObject();
     reader.close();
        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }catch (IOException ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when i run this `IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1`.I am using a separate class to set and get fields in json.How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you import

```
 import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
```

Don't convert it to String, pass reader directly to gson.

```
Employee employee= gson.fromJson(reader, Employee.class);
```

Comment: But when i use it without converting android studio notify it as error and says "cannot resolve fromjson(....)"

Comment: from reader accepts JsonReader as parameter, it must be something different. Because I just copy pasted your code and tried, it works ok without converting. Are you sure you use correct method? above should work properly. Just one thing, do you use jsonfrom or jsonFrom ? or it was just mentioning

Comment: probably you use the wrong import, check your imports and make sure you imported import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader; not  the  android.util.JsonReader;

Comment: yes you are correct i make the wrong import.After changing it ,works.

Comment: glad that it works now. Would be nice if you accept the answer for the further for other people who might have the same problem.